# doubling strategy, martingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

I am reading this wikipedia article : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(betting_system)

I don't understand section mathematical analysis of a single round. Single round is defined to be series of loses ending with win or lose. So elements of sample space is {W, LW, LLW, LLLW, LLLLW, ... (n-1)LW, nL} where for example LLW means lose lose win and (n-1)LW means n-1 loses and win in that order. Let $q=\frac{1}{2}$ for simplicity. Why is probability of losing all money $\frac{1}{2^n}$ and not $\frac{1}{n+1}$. $\frac{1}{2^n}$ suggests that there are possibilites such as WLW(n-3)L but after a win game is over.

I understand that rules could be that after a win we bet again and it is still the same round but then when calculating expected value should be different because if we win twice we earn $2$ coins if we win three times we earn $3$ coins and if we win $k$ out of $n$ times we earn $k$ coins.

What is wrong?

Comment: For example WLWLLL would mean we did not stop with the first win, even though it *should* be "series of losses followed by a single loss or win."

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: there can be any number of L's followed by a W. Or just all L's. The point is that IF you ever get W the game stops. [So WLWLLL would not be right]

Comment: Exactly, that is my point

Answer (score 1):

While the sample space is, as you wrote, $\{W,LW,...,(n-1)LW,nL\}$, the probability measure is not the uniform measure.  Not all elements of the sample space are equally likely.  Here, $P(W) > P(LW)$, for example.  Even though there are only $n+1$ elements, the probability of $W$ is still $\frac 12$, the probability of $LW$ is still $\frac 14$, etc.  Indeed, the probability of $n$ losses is still $\frac 1{2^n}$.  This doesn't imply that there are $2^n$ elements in the sample space.

Comment: So what is sample space?

Comment: @romperextremeabuser Per the first sentence of my answer, "the sample space is, as you wrote, $\{W,LW,...,(n-1)LW,nL\}$"